# transfer from one contract to another

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, assembly

```
// ContractA
function nice(address to) public payable {
     require(_to.send(_value), ERROR_SEND_REVERTED);
}
```

I also have a contractB which was deployed with EIP-1167. Now, The problem is that when I call contractA's nice function and pass contractB address, it fails.

The reason it fails is that contractB is a proxy contract, so it needs to call delegateCall first, and delegateCall costs 2600 Gas Cost which is more than 2300 Gas Cost for send. I tried using access List and it worked, but the problem is that access list only worked if used Ethers.js Wallet. if you use this with metamask or any other wallets, it fails, because none of the wallets support access list .

I tried to write a middle contract that will receive funds and that middle contract will forward the funds to the proxy contract, but this time, instead of send, i'd use call to send funds. The problem with this is that I can't really make this middle contract safe. For example, let's look at it

```js
contract MIddle {


    receive() {
        emit myEvent(msg.data, msg.value, msg.sender)
    }

    function migrate(address _to, uint256 value) {
        _to.call({value: value})
    }


}
```

If you observe, this is really unsafe, because anyone can call migrate now. I can't have any kind of state checks who is eligible to call it or not, because how do I make this state at all ? receive can only use 2300 Gas so it can only emit events which means i won't have any state.

Is there any other choice/way to solve this ? I'd appreciate your answer so much